# ERROR: Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-tree'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular6

I added the example retrieved from https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview (The example can be seen[https://stackblitz.com/angular/arbvompqpmg?file=main.ts]) the documentation but it throw this error:

```
Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-tree'.
1. If 'mat-tree' is an Angular component and it has 'dataSource' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tree' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I added both

```
import {CdkTreeModule} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
```

and

```
import {MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material';
```

My current versions are:

```
"@angular/animations": "^6.0.6",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.3.0",
"@angular/common": "^6.0.6",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.0.6",
"@angular/core": "^6.0.6",
"@angular/forms": "^6.0.6",
"@angular/http": "^6.0.6",
"@angular/material": "^6.3.0",
```

Do you have any idea about how to solve this problem?
I read other solutions and everybody explains to add correct imports, so I did but the problem still.

Comment: did you import in related module.ts

Comment: it usually happens when you haven't imported and added the module required. have you added the MatTreeModule to your app.ts module imports ?

Comment: @yer I added only in main.ts. solved adding it into the related module.ts
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please refrain from adding "SOLVED" to the title and adding the answer to the question.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you might not have imported CdkTreeModule and MatTreeModule in module.ts related to the component.